# Picking numbers in an order

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I had a task to slide images from a mysql database using jquery slide and not the animation scripts. The slide is supposed to show at least the most recent ten images that was uploaded. With that I first of all wrote a random query

```
mysql_query("select * from tblname order by rand() limit 1);
```

But as expected, it picks the images at random irrespective of when it was posted and of course it wasn't the most recent ten. After some thought I now had to first run a query to get the most recent ten

```
mysql_query("select * from tblname order by ID limit 10);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql){
    $slideid=$slideid.",".$row['recordid'];
}
```

this of course results to a variable of this order

```
$var="23,22,24,34,27,78,56,87,98,55";
```

I tried handling it like an array but it wasn't giving any positive result, hence I had an issue of how to pick this numbers and use it for the slide

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with the numbers?

Comment: fill them in an array (you can use explode), and sort the array?

Comment: @Utkanos please I want to run a query with the numbers

Comment: @DimgbaKalu do you need them sorted - ie lowest first ?

Comment: I think this is more mysql related, you could try something like this `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id_column IN({$var})`

Comment: @Dale yes this is more mysql related. However, the for each solved a part of the issue, the problem here is that it brought out every thing at the same time despite the where clause I used

Comment: this is what I did
$slideid="23,22,24,34,27,78,56,87,98,55";
$arr = explode(',',$slideid);
foreach ($arr as $val) {
   //lets get the variables from the form post
 $rs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblname WHERE id='$val'") or die(mysql_error());
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($rs)){
             echo "<img src='image/$image'>";
        }
}

the images are displayed one by one using jquery slide

Comment: @DimgbaKalu I've added an answer I hope it helps you out.

Comment: @Dale thanks I've seen the answer but I still have the same problem. It pulls all the result but I want it to display the image one after the other via jquery. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments I will offer my 2p into the mix

> this is what I did $slideid="23,22,24,34,27,78,56,87,98,55"; $arr =
>   explode(',',$slideid); foreach ($arr as $val) { //lets get the
>   variables from the form post $rs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblname
>   WHERE id='$val'") or die(mysql_error());
>   while($row=mysql_fetch_array($rs)){ echo "<img src='image/$image'>"; }
>   } the images are displayed one by one using jquery slide

Now I think we are wasting time dealing with exploding this variable because mysql has the nifty IN() function (possibly in other db's I don't know)

```
$slideid = "23,22,24,34,27,78,56,87,98,55";
$rs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblname WHERE id IN({$slideid})") or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs))
{
    echo "<img src='image/{$row['image']}' />";
}
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Building on your reply, which I totally agree with you can write the SQL to be `SELECT * FROM tblname WHERE id IN({$slideid}) order by id` which would pretty much do the trick start to finish. +1 from me.

Comment: @Fluffeh Cheers fella much appreciated, I think this question is very misleading now I come back to it, everyone has answered roughly the same thing whether attacked via php or mysql and the asker has asked the wrong question!

Comment: @Fluffeh yes..this absolutely did helped. However, it showed all the images at once so I had to order by rand and limit to 1 at a time...

Answer (score 5):

```
$myArr=explode(',',$var);
sort($myArr);

for($i=0;$i<count($myArr);$i++)
{
    echo $myArr[$i];
}
```

Edit: For better efficiency use:

```
$myArr=explode(',',$var);
sort($myArr);

foreach ($myArr as $val)
{
    echo $val;
    // Or do whatever else you want with each one.
}
```

Edit 2: See comments below on efficiency vs for loops vs unexpected results. :)

Comment: `foreach` is faster in this case. If you are not forced to use `for` loop in most cases it's better to use `foreach` in PHP.

Comment: @PLB can you give me an instance of the for...each statement

Comment: @Fluffeh: If he wants it guaranteed to be in order he should used a for loop, foreach relies on the internal pointer changing and can sometimes lead to unexpected behavior.

Comment: @Fluffeh this is what I did
$slideid="23,22,24,34,27,78,56,87,98,55";
$arr = explode(',',$slideid);
foreach ($arr as $val) {
   //lets get the variables from the form post
 $rs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblname WHERE id='$val'") or die(mysql_error());
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($rs)){
             echo "<img src='image/$image'>";
        }
}

the images are displayed one by one using jquery slide

Comment: @DimgbaKalu It's really late here and I am heading to bed. If this solved your problem, please Accept the answer, if not I will have a look in the morning or some other kind chap will add a comment or edit my post.

Answer (score 1):

```
$var="23,22,24,34,27,78,56,87,98,55";
$arr = explode(',',$var);
foreach ($arr as $val) {
   // work with $val
}
```

[`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) splits the string to an array

Comment: this is what I did
$slideid="23,22,24,34,27,78,56,87,98,55";
$arr = explode(',',$slideid);
foreach ($arr as $val) {
   //lets get the variables from the form post
 $rs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblname WHERE id='$val'") or die(mysql_error());
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($rs)){
             echo "<img src='image/$image'>";
        }
}

the images are displayed one by one using jquery slide

Answer (score 0):

1) Explode the string into an array, splitting on the comma.

2) You didn't say whether you wanted to re-order the numbers into numerical order, or process them in the order they're already in. If the former, sort the array with `sort($arr);`

3) Loop over the array in sequence and do something with each number

```
$str = '1,2,3,4,5,6';
$arr = explode(',', $str);
foreach($arr as $num) echo $num.'<br />';
```

Note if there is any change of spaces after commas, a better choice would be `preg_split` rather than `explode`, as this is more dynamic.

```
$arr = preg_split('/, ?/', $str);
```

Comment: You should use `1.`, `2.` (instead of `1)`, `2)`) for a better ordered list

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using php **[explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)** function

$pieces = explode(",", $var);

echo $pieces[0]; // piece1

echo $pieces[1](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php); // piece2

.

.

.

echo $pieces[n]; // piece n

Comment: How would this sort them into the lowest to highest order as the poster asked?

Comment: $sortedData = sort($pieces,SORT_NUMERIC);

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to get result of order with respect to order of variable here

```
$slideid = "23,22,24,34,27,78,56,87,98,55";
$rs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblname WHERE id IN({$slideid}) ORDER BY FIELD(id, {$slideid}) ") or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs))
{
    echo "<img src='image/{$row['image']}' />";
}
```